# Заголовок ответа HTTP Strict-Transport-Security (HSTS)

Tags: http, сеть, https

Наткнулся на такой ранее не виданный для меня термин, как "HTTP Strict-Transport-Security (HSTS)".

В интернете вычитал, что то типа это:

> Что собой представляет поддержка HSTS При вводе домена в адресной
> строке без протокола https либо в формате «site.ru» в браузере сперва
> выводится незащищенная версия сайта. Даже если на нем установлен
> SSL-сертификат, перенаправление происходит уже после первого перехода.
> Этим моментом пользуются мошенники с целью перехвата данных
> пользователя и перенаправления его на подставную страницу.
>
> HSTS — это алгоритм взаимодействия между браузером и сервером, при
> котором сайту присваивается статус защищенного на заданный период. Это
> делается с помощью заголовка HTTP Strict Transport Security. Он
> выдается при ответе сервера и указывает браузеру на необходимость
> постоянной автоматической переадресации на версию сайта под протоколом
> https.

Но, я что то не понимаю, зачем это все такие нужно ?
Ну для примера: набираю я в браузере ru.stackoverflow.com - браузер запрашивает IP-адреса у DNS или достает кэшированные.

Далее браузер посылает запрос на выданный диапазон IP адресов. Браузер не знает по какому порту работает удаленный сервер, но в чем проблема сначала попытается послать и получить http-запрос именно по 443 порту, просто по умолчанию для всех адресов использовать 443 порт и TSL, "двойное рукопожатие" и прочие https защитные алгоритмы.

Зачем по факту то нужен этот HSTS ?

И вообще так же не понятен этот момент:

> Что собой представляет поддержка HSTS При вводе домена в адресной
> строке без протокола https либо в формате «site.ru» в браузере сперва
> выводится незащищенная версия сайта.
> Даже если на нем установлен
> SSL-сертификат, перенаправление происходит уже после первого перехода.
> Этим моментом пользуются мошенники с целью перехвата данных
> пользователя и перенаправления его на подставную страницу.

Если сайт работает пo https на 443 порту, то с какого перепуга сервер выдаст html страницу не по https, а не отклонит запрос с сообщением Bad_request ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что если злоумышленник обрубит 443 порт, то браузер попробует использовать 80 порт — опа, незашифрованный! HSTS предотвращает такую возможность

Comment: @andreymal, так пусть использует 80ый в чем проблема ? Северов НЕ должен отвечать на запросы через 80 порт или должен, но только о том, что через 80 порт не обслуживаем. Хотя до меня только, что скорее всего дошло, что HTTP Strict-Transport-Security - это и есть ответ сервера на попытку запроса по 80 порту, что "по 80му порту не обслуживаем дарагой". Так получается ?

Comment: Так серверу совершенно не обязательно отвечать на 80 порт! Если между клиентом и сервером сядет злоумышленник, он заблокирует клиенту 443 порт и станет принимать от клиента запросы по 80 порту и отправит ему в ответ «по 80 порту обслуживаем дорогой», а на сервер будет перенаправлять клиентские запросы по 443 порту, и сервер ничего не заподозрит. В итоге у клиента шифрования нет, сервер думает что шифрование есть, а злоумышленник успешно читает все секреты.

Comment: @andreymal, а вот этого не понял. Предположим между клиентом и сервером злоумышленник. Предположим сервер не обслуживает по 80порту, а только по 443. Я в браузере набираю ru.stackoverflow.com. Что делает злой умышленник ?

Comment: Ещё раз — злоумышленник блокирует вам доступ по 443 порту, и в итоге у вас открывается незашифрованный 80 порт, который полностью под контролем злоумышленника и который может делать с ним что угодно, даже перенаправить на поддельный сервер

Comment: @andreymal, что мешает злоумышленнику блокировать мне доступ по 443 порту и перенаправить по 80 порту сразу на поддельный сервер при наличии на сервере HSTS ?

Comment: Мешает то, что после получения HSTS-заголовка браузер запомнит, что ходить на этот сервер без шифрования нельзя, и он никогда-никогда не станет ходить по 80 порту, даже если злоумышленник заблокирует 443 порт

Comment: @andreymal, злоумышленник УЖЕ первоначально перехватил мой запрос на ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ сервер и перенаправил его, как вы писали по 80 порту на поддельный. В этой схеме Правильного сервера и его HSTS вообще нет. У вас, как мне кажется путаница, кто появился раньше курица или яйцо.

Comment: Поэтому нужно зарегистрировать свой домен в [HSTS Preload List](https://hstspreload.org/) — тогда информация о том, что ваш сайт нельзя посещать незашифрованным, будет зашита прямо внутри браузера, и посетить незашифрованную версию сайта будет вообще невозможно никак

Comment: @andreymal, теперь понял. Спасибо!